# How do I tell if two sets of dots are in some way similar?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, geometry

I have two sets of dots (x,y coordinates) and I'd like to figure out if there's a way to find out if the second set of dots is (more or less) "close" to the first one.

I may plot these two sets in two functions, but I don't know a way to tell if they are in some way similar.

Basically, what I have to do is:

1. collect some sets of data (sets of dots) as references for future classification;
2. collect one more set of data (this one is an "unknown" set);
3. compare the last set data to the ones collected before and see if it is somehow similar to the previous ones.

What I'm missing now is the third point: what is a way to "compare" these sets of data?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have a look here [Scientific Data Analysis](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScientificDataAnalysis.html)

Comment: Does the ordering matter? Would you consider `Table[ {i, i}, {i, 1, 5}]` and `Table[ {6-i, 6-i}, {i, 1, 5}]` to be similar or different?

Comment: And do the sets contain equal number of dots?

Comment: Are you wanting something that allows for rotation and scaling? If so you will want to preprocess with `SingularValueDecomposition`. After which maybe the proposed methods using `Nearest` would be a reasonable way to proceed.

Comment: This question seems to be a statistical question better suited for Cross Validated rather than this forum.  The selection process associated with the data needs to be explicitly considered.  Samples might be made on the same experimental unit and the repeated measures aspect would influence how to interpret and construct any measure of similarity.

Comment: Closely related: [Find the nearest locations for multiple points](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63779/4678)

Comment: For whatever it's worth my comment above about using Cross Validated is that how two datasets should be compared is not an intrinsic feature of the data.  It comes from outside of the data and requires (or should require) specifics about objectives, how good one needs the comparison, what are the consequences of choosing any particular measure, etc.  My comment is not at all about the quality of the question or how interesting the question is.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the two sets are related by some kind of geometric transformation you could use `FindGeometricTransform` for this.

As a demonstration let's generate some random points:

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {50, 2}];
```

Add a bit of noise and transform to get a second set:

```
at = AffineTransform[{{0.9, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.9}}];
distPoints = at /@ (RandomReal[1] + # & /@ points);
```

Show the sets:

```
Graphics[
 {
  Blue,
  Point@points,
  Red,
  Point@distPoints
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now find the transformation connecting the two sets:

```
{er, trans} = FindGeometricTransform[distPoints, points]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Transform the first set with the transformation found and see how they compare:

```
Graphics[
 {
  Blue,
  Point@(trans /@ points),
  Red,
  Point@distPoints
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The small differences that are left will be caused by the random error we added.

You could use the error term (assigned to `er` above) as a measure of the similarity of the two data sets (assuming that you would regard two sets that differ only by a geometric transformation as being the same).

Note that you can constrain the type of transformation that `FindGeometricTranslation` looks for by using the `TransformationClass` option.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the two data sets have five points each:

```
data1 = Table[RandomReal[], {5}, {2}]

data2 = Table[RandomReal[], {5}, {2}]

EuclideanDistance @@ {Flatten[(Nearest @@ {data1, data2}), 1], data1}
```

(* 0.819504 *)

Why this works:

```
Flatten[(Nearest @@ {data1, data2}), 1]
```

finds the nearest point in `data2` for each successive point in `data1`.

Then `EuclideanDistance @@ ...` finds the overall distance.

Check:  `EuclideanDistance @@ {Flatten[(Nearest @@ {data1, data1}), 1], data1}`

(* 0 *)

Comment: I have not tested so I'll ask. Does this enforce that each point in one set has a unique corresponding point in the other? Maybe it doesn't matter too much once you account for the differences in both directions.

Comment: It does not enforce one point to one point.  Is that what you seek?

Comment: Well, if you have say four points clustered in one case, they might all be close to one particular point in the other. Meanwhile that other might have four clustered points that are near to the remaining point in the first set. Do we want to consider those as similar? My initial thought was we do not, but now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

This finds nearest matches and eliminates each pair from further consideration.

```
data1 = Table[RandomReal[], {100}, {2}];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .1], 2] + # & /@ 
          RandomSample[data1, 80];
aligndata = NestWhile[ 
   (pair = 
      Position[#, Min[#]][[1]] &@ 
       Outer[ EuclideanDistance , #[[1]], #[[2]], 
        1]; {Drop[#[[1]], {pair[[1]]}], Drop[#[[2]], {pair[[2]]}], 
      Append[#[[3]],
       {#[[1, pair[[1]]]], #[[2, pair[[2]]]]}]}) &
    , {data1, data2, {}}, Length@#[[1]] > 0 && Length@#[[2]] > 0 &  ];

 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.015], Point[data1], Blue, Point[data2], 
    Black, Line /@ aligndata[[3]]}]
```

[image]

I'm not sure how to quantify the correlation.  Total length of lines `EuclideanDistance @@ # & /@ aligndata[[3]] // Total` plus some accounting for missing data?