# How to get some pairing with smallest total distance in high effciency method

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have two point set

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[pts1], Blue, Point[pts2]}]
```

[image]

I want to get a match for every point,If I use `Transpose` directly,the total distance will very big like

```
pairs = Transpose[{pts1, pts2}];
totalDist = Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ pairs]
```

> 5.29783

How to get such pairs with smallest total distance in a high effciency method?

Comment: The [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) might help.

Comment: As far as I am aware [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108990/6588) is one of the fastest implementations for the assignment problem on this site. It returns a total distance of 2.54317 in under 1ms for your test case.

Comment: Why can Community mark a question duplicate by itself (without voting)?

Comment: @happyfish But it seem it is exactly a duplicate post~

Comment: @yode that's true, I just wonder why is the bot that sure about it.