# How to find the a minimum cost perfect matching

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization, algorithm, code-request

Crossposted on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1073680)

---

A a minimum cost perfect matching is very useful tool.This three links about this demand just related me,let alone all *MMA.SE*.

- [How to get some pairing with smallest total distance in high
  effciency
  method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141176/how-to-get-some-pairing-with-smallest-total-distance-in-high-effciency-method)
- [How to get a pair with smallest total distance from one list in
  high-efficiency
  method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143193/how-to-get-a-pair-with-smallest-total-distance-from-one-list-in-high-efficiency)
- [How to get the Perfect Matching or Near-Perfect
  Matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111576/how-to-get-the-perfect-matching-or-near-perfect-matching)

But the in-built `FindIndependentEdgeSet` seem treat weight graph as non-weight graph directly,this often make me depressed.I found a ready-made algorithm for min cost perfect matching [here](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software.html#BLOSSOM5).But as this declaration

> The code above is licensed for research purposes only.

I don't sure *Wolfram Research* will have impetus to add this feature for `FindIndependentEdgeSet` in future.Can anyone be willing to implement this algorithm in *Mathematica* or more high efficiency method to improve `FindIndependentEdgeSet`?As I know,*Blossom V* itself is very high-efficiency.

Also,I hope the answer can meet a **additional** demand,that is it can accept *negative* edge weight value.Then if we use the *negative* weight value,we can get a maximal cost perfect matching,which is promising.

Help to imporove *Mathematica*,Help me,Please.

Comment: I feel like I've answered this before, here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109899/242 and here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112221/242. Both answers find a minimum cost perfect matching, IIRC?

Comment: Regarding negative weights: why not just add a constant to all weights to make them nonnegative? This will add the same constant to all possible matchings, so it will not change the result

Comment: Hello @nikie,note the difference of this question.Of course,it relate with my [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143193/21532),which is about how to get a match with min cost from **one list** (against your [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111576/how-to-get-the-perfect-matching-or-near-perfect-matching)) and hard define a direction cost(against your [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112221/242))

Comment: @nikie As your [second comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143344/how-to-find-the-a-minimum-cost-perfect-matching?noredirect=1#comment386082_143344),see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Akexi.png),please.